# Selenium - keeping track of dynamic row xpath while scrolling (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, dynamic, scroll

[Website containing scrollable table](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiY2QwODc2YjEtZjc0YS00OTk1LTkyNzgtMjA2NGY2YzI0YzFhIiwidCI6ImEzYTBjMDEyLTdhNTQtNDlmNC05MDc5LTdmZjU0ZjZkMGI1ZiIsImMiOjF9)

I'm scraping data from this table. To do so, I need to be able to scroll down continuously while also keeping track of where I am so I can scrape the data as I go.

I've been able to use actions to scroll down after clicking on the table. This is the code that works:

```
driver.get('https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiY2QwODc2YjEtZjc0YS00OTk1LTkyNzgtMjA2NGY2YzI0YzFhIiwidCI6ImEzYTBjMDEyLTdhNTQtNDlmNC05MDc5LTdmZjU0ZjZkMGI1ZiIsImMiOjF9')  

click_row = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@role='row'])[2]") 
action = ActionChains(driver) action.move_to_element(click_row).click().perform()  #click so I can scroll

top_row = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@role='presentation'])[5]/div[1]")
while top_row.get_attribute('row-index') != '19':
    ActionChains(driver)\
        .key_down(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)\
        .perform()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    top_row = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@role='presentation'])[5]/div[1]")
    print(top_row.get_attribute('row-index'))
```

I was hoping that I could keep track of the topmost row displayed on the table. When I scroll down the table on the webpage and inspect, I'm able to see that `(//div[@role='presentation'])[5]/div[1]` does keep changing. But when run the code and print it, the row number stays constant, so I have no way of tracking it.

Any idea on what's happening?